# Deploying ASPNET core app in IIS inside Docker Container

Tags: asp.net, iis, docker, asp.net-core, windows-server-container

I have been working with docker for some days and since I am trying the possibilities of docker, recently faced a problem about how to deploy an ASP.NET core app in a webserver inside Docker container. Deploying an ASP.NET 4.5 app is successful using IIS and WindowsServerCore but can anybody suggest how exactly to containerize a webserver running asp.net core app.

PS. I don't want the app to run in debug mode so I do not want "dotnet run" answers please. I want the built version of the app to be deployed in the webserver, any suggestions as to how?

Comment: Hi Abhirup Guha - can you show us what you have tried so far, i.e. your dockerfile, and describe precisely what is going wrong? This question is too broad to know how to answer, until you [edit] it to give us more detail.

Comment: IIS does "dotnet run" to run ASP.Net Core applications and merely acts as a reverse proxy. I wrote a blog post describing how IIS runs ASP.Net Core apps - https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/. I hope it will point you in the right direction.